# What is the script to use in Autohotkey to make "Insert" trigger "Alt+Shift+I" in chrome?

Tags: autohotkey

I need the answer to just this question in order to enter other hotkeys. And later on, I will be using hotstrings as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give us examples? Please try to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what you're doing, I can only give you the ingredients to do what you described.

```
; make the title matching sufficiently liberal
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
;wait for the hotkey
return
; put this before your hotkey to have it only fire if a window containing these words in it's title is active
#IfWinActive , Google Chrome
Ins::  ; trigger this code when insert pressed
     sendinput {alt down}I{alt up} ;it's capital, so no need for shift.
     ;alternatively the shorthand for that
     sendinput !I
     ;helpful for debugging.
     tooltip The hotkey fired. Did chrome respond the way you wanted?
     sleep 2000 ;wait 2 seconds before hiding tooltip
     tooltip   ;empty tooltip means no tooltip
 ;end your hotkey. Otherwise it will keep going and execute the next hotkey once you make more.
 return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

That's a list of the key names you can put in place of `Ins` or you can put them in your `sendinput` command like this:

```
sendinput {Ins}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Insert::!+i  ; Pressing Insert will send Alt+Shift+I.
#IfWinActive
```